# Intellij fat one jar artifact does not generate a working output

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, executable-jar

Intellij fat one jar artifact does not generate a working output. Below you can see my settings and project structure(**left**). When i click **build artifact** and then the generated output, nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output in the command line when you run it as `java -jar …`?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Could not find main class or load

Comment: If any of the jars you add to the dependencies has its own `META-INF/Manifest.MF` file, it will override the manifest where you specify the main class, [see here for the solution](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000120864--SOLVED-How-to-turn-a-mixed-Kotlin-Java-project-with-a-Kotlin-file-as-main-class-into-a-JAR-?page=1#community_comment_115000144030).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, tried it and still getting same error "COuld not find main class or load" etc.. **See edited picture please**. Maybe one lib i am depending on is project library, can problem be tied to that?

Comment: What's inside the generated jar manifest file? Does it specify the correct main class?

Comment: Yes it is, see new image on the question pls.

Comment: Do you have this class in the jar? What's the source structure? Show this main class in the editor and the project view.

Comment: Yes it has the main class in the jar file. I added image for you. What do you mean by source structure? It is javafx project with ant build i guess. İ didnt touch any other settings. Can 2 version of java being installed can be problem?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's hard to tell what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: what? You are given everything you asked for. **Check the new image**.  It is illogical to write "question is not enough" after you asked so many questions.

Comment: I mean that everything looks correct from what you have provided, so I can't tell what can be wrong without looking at the project myself locally.

Comment: For example, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153017/intellij-project-executable-not-doing-anything#comment77276558_45153017), user didn't specify the correct file name. There could be also something else that is hard to spot from the screenshots.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dckwabbbod6n8rz/LdapTool.zip?dl=0 can you look at it if you have time. Thanks

Comment: `mssql-jdbc-6.2.0.jre8.jar` has the digital signature (`MSFTSIG.RSA`
and `MSFTSIG.SF` files). When the jar is repackaged, the signature becomes broken. If you remove these files from the jar, it should start fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mssql-jdbc-6.2.0.jre8.jar` has the digital signature (`MSFTSIG.RSA` and `MSFTSIG.SF` files). When the jar is repackaged, the signature becomes broken. If you remove these files from the jar (either original one or the artifact), it should start fine.

[Vote for this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-147551) to get it addressed in the future updates.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Last question.. Should i remove it from output jar or from lib's folder one? (Couldn't find it in the jar)

Comment: If you remove it from the artifact, you will have to do it every time you rebuild the jar, so it makes sense to [remove it from the lib instead](http://i.imgur.com/JEFln4h.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder how I can find which jar causing the problem?

Comment: @KostasC extract the jars and see if there are `*.SF/*.RSA` files inside.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder.  It took me a while to find this question but it gave me a good pointer. In my case the file in question is
lorg.conscript:conscrypt-openjdk-uber: 2.5.1 containing the RSA.
Removal allowed the application to run.
I now have to find out what I may have broken by removing this library jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened generated jar file with winrar. And deleted `SIGNINGC.SF` file in `META-INF` folder