# JNI Error followed by Java Error when opening exectuable-jar

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, deployment, executable-jar

Good evening,

I encountered a problem while building an executable jar with Intellij. Before I never encountered Problems with it, but this time there is JNI Error occured and a Java Error occured message. I already tried the tips I found in Stackoverflow. It won't work with Maven Assembly Plugin or Maven Dependency Plugin. Moreover I tried creating the MANIFEST in main/java and main/resources. When I create it in main/java nothing happens when i open the jar with the second method the error mentioned earlier occures.

[The only way it works is using this option in Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GrFQ.png)

But using this option all of the libraries are in the file Path individually and the jar size is 75 kb. My goal was to create ONE fat executable jar. Btw another maven project I created works finde after creating the jar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891, also check [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116209#focus=streamItem-27-656589-0-0). To get more help share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Wow im dumb as ****! The second thread was the answer, I saw it already but I accidentally missed one file path. Thanks!