# How to start class from IntelliJ generated jar?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, kotlin, jar

So I build an artifact using intellij. When I try to run class from jar (that is in current folder named `cordapp.jar`)

```
java -cp "cordapp.jar" com.template.NodeDriver
```

It can not find a class.

I extract .jar into a folder, cd into it, run:

```
java -cp . com.template.NodeDriver
```

It starts as expected.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Does `java -jar cordapp.jar com.template.NodeDriver` work?

Comment: @CrazyCoder: sadly it does not make any difference

Comment: @DuckQueen see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/54915137/104891 is the case. If not, share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DuckQueen any updates on the issue?