# Problem launching corda jar: newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater

Tags: kotlin, jar, corda

I've tried to launch (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083718/how-to-start-class-from-intellij-generated-jar)) corda standalone jar and encountered a problem:

```
    internal.DriverDSLImpl.genericDriver - Driver shutting down because of exception 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater; 
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:32) ~[corda/:?] 
    at io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Unpooled.java:199) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer.(TimedBuffer.java:111) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFileFactory.(AbstractSequentialFileFactory.java:78) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFileFactory.(NIOSequentialFileFactory.java:75) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.init(JournalStorageManager.java:132) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:217) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.(JournalStorageManager.java:103) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createStorageManager(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2008) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart1(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2145) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:63) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:516) ~[corda/:?] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:464) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.configureAndStartServer(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:122) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.start(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:92) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startMessagingService(Node.kt:294) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:256) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:700) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:152) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:138) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:699) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:347) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:207) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:361) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:805) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:767) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119) ~[corda/:?] 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22) ~[corda/:?] 
    at

    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche..(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202] 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf 
    at io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Unpooled.java:199) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer.(TimedBuffer.java:111) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFileFactory.(AbstractSequentialFileFactory.java:78) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFileFactory.(NIOSequentialFileFactory.java:75) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.init(JournalStorageManager.java:132) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:217) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.(JournalStorageManager.java:103) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createStorageManager(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2008) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart1(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2145) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:63) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:516) 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:464) 
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.configureAndStartServer(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:122) 
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.start(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:92) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startMessagingService(Node.kt:294) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:256) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:700) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:152) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:138) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:699) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:347) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:207) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:361) 
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:805) 
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:767) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) 
    at

    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche..(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Corda (4.0+), you do not need to put the driver as args any more. You can simply start the node by:

```
java -jar corda.jar
```

You can even allocate more RAM for the entire JVM inside your build.gradle file, so you node startup might be quicker:

```
extraConfig = ['jvmArgs' : [ "-Xmx2048m", "-Xms512m", "-XX:+UseG1GC" ] ]
```