# Jar Built by IntelliJ not recognizing libraries inside jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

In IntelliJ it gives you the option to put a library (dependency) to the artifact you are creating. I want to do this because some of the libraries I have are digitally signed and if I extract them to the jar it causes it to not run (no main method found)

However when I do this I get a bunch of exceptions saying that the class cannot be found. Is there a special way I have to configure this jar setup so that this will be able to find the jars within the artifact?

Comment: Why don't you do using Maven or Gradle instead of using any IDE ? It is pretty simple and better.

Comment: I am using maven, however I still need to extract the jars into the runnable artifact which is where I am having the issue

Comment: Look into this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven. You have to create a fat jar file using maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The previous maven set up solved this issue for me. Then I ran mvn clean package and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Jar file placed inside another jar will not work out of the box with IntelliJ IDEA. It requires a custom classloader to handle such dependencies. You either put the [jars next to the main jar and link them via manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891) or you [strip the digital signature from the dependent jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891) and unpack their contents into the single jar.

Your another option is to build the jar via the Maven or Gradle plug-ins which can handle the signed jars better.