# How to generate a runnable artifact with modules in intelliJ (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, module

I'm trying to make a runnable jar for an application with IntelliJ. The application is a Spring application made from 2 separated modules, a bdd_module and a service_module.
The service_module use the bdd_module.

I created an artifact, built it and launched it as said here :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

I got the following error :
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.need_a_name.game_service.Game_Service

How can I make a runnable jar ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Here are the artifact view :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPhwp.png
And the module view :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J5AC.jpg

I tried to move the manifest file to the resources folder instead of the java folder.
I also tried the things indicated here :
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when running in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660125/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-when-running-in-intellij-idea/42660624#42660624)

Thanks for reading this and for your time

EDIT :
Here is what is in my generated jar :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSGP8.png

Comment: Did you check that https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891 is not the case? The final jar may have signatures from some of the dependent jars you are unpacking inside of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CrazyCoder.
I've seen this post, but I don't found the MSFTSIG.RSA and MSFTSIG.SF in the generated jar.
Thinking about it, I should add to the question a screenshot of what is in the generated jar. Will had that tomorrow.