# Creating a .jar file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar, graphstream

I have a project that uses `GraphStream` (http://graphstream-project.org/) it's just a normal project (not Maven or Gradle). I seem to be able to include `GraphStream`, but whenever I try to make a `.jar` file `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again` appears. I've tried to make a `.jar file` without it and it seems to work just fine, but it's crucial to have it there since it draws a graph at the end of the execution.

Could `GraphStream` be too old for usage? Is there a way to bypass this? Any help would be appreciated. I am using IntelliJ Community Version.

I've tried making an uber-jar (or fat-jar) but the same error seems to appear.

Here are all of the classes and the .jar file
[image: classes and the .jar file]

Here are the dependencies of the GraphStream (downloaded via Maven).

[image: dependencies]

And this is the problem that I get whenever I try to run the `.jar` in IntelliJ.
[image]

Comment: Include the two jars in the lib folder in your classpath and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly and https://spring.io/guides/gs/intellij-idea/

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb did the exact same thing, still the same problem. I am pretty much sure I've tried this before too.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder maybe the edit will be of some help?

Comment: Yes, it does, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891.

Comment: Bouncycastle libraries you have embedded have the digital signatures. I'm not sure there is an easy way having a fat jar with these security libs (bc*). See https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/227.

Comment: @CrazyCoder removing those signature helped! Thank you a lot.
Although I am facing another problem now - Whenever I run the .jar file from IntelliJ it works fine, GraphStream works and it shows the things I need. However, when I run it directly from the .jar file (without IntelliJ) GraphStream doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Make sure command line has the same options and the same JDK version is used.